# Popup message window in grails?

Tags: grails, popup, message

I have a Grails application with a form in it.  Once the user has entered the data and submitted it, and it's been validated etc.. I need a message to popup in a little window to give the user some feedback - it needs to popup, rather than be displayed on the page.  Can anyone advise me on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented the same mechanism for my application, and I am using the jQuery plugin 'smartmodal' (used by the Nimble plugin originally). See [here](http://www.oneblackbear.com/projects/jquery-plugin-smart-modal)

You simply have to redirect the request in the controller validation code to a GSP page containing the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(file: 'jquery-1.3.2.js')}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(file:'jquery.smartmodal.js')}"></script>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="./css/smartmodal.css">
...
<body>
...
<g:javascript>
$(function() { 
 $("#msg").hide();
 $("#msg").modal({hide_on_overlay_click:false});
 $("#msg").modal_show();});
</g:javascript>
<div id="msg">
My feedback message is here 
</div>
<g:link controller="..." action="...">Close</g:link>
```

I hope it helps,

Fabien

**EDIT**:
An extract of the `smartmodal.css` file that will render the 'modal effect' is:

```
#modal_content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 10%;

    background: #FFF;
    border: 0px solid #d2d2d2;

    width: 400px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    text-align: left;
}

#modal_overlay {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

However if you want the complete file, it is available inside the great [Nimble](http://intient.com/opensource/nimble) grails plugin

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - I'm struggling a bit with it though, when it redirects it opens this in the main window rather than a little window. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: If the main window appears instead of the modal window, it means that the 'modal_show()' function is not called or that the CSS file smartmodal.css is not included. I would check that both JS and CSS files are included into your html page. I have updated the code for including the CSS file

Comment: ok great, I could only find a modal.css in the zip from the link you suggested, but that does not seem to work - is the smartmodal.css different to the modal.css one?  thankyou so much for your help

Comment: I think that you better have to install Nimble (http://intient.com/opensource/nimble) into a new grails application and just go over the plugin code.